# http request cancelled on javascript html5 audio preload

Tags: javascript, http, html5-audio, persistent-connection

I'm trying to preload audio files with javascript. I'm using chrome,
When the number of files growing up the http request of my files are cancelled by chrome...
why? what can i do?
This is my code:

```
filesToLoad = 44;
filesLoaded = 0;

for ( var ni = 1; ni < filesToLoad; ni++) {

    console.log("start::: " + ServerPath + 'audio/' + ni + '.mp3');
    loadAudio(ServerPath + 'audio/' + ni + '.mp3');
}

function loadAudio(uri) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', isAppLoaded, true); // It
    audio.src = uri;
    return audio;
}

function isAppLoaded() {
    filesLoaded++;
    if (filesLoaded >= filesToLoad) {
        cb();
    }
    console.log("load::: " + ServerPath + 'audio/' + filesLoaded + '.mp3');
}

function cb() {
    alert("loaded");
}
```

Comment: Preloading audio and video in HTML5 is a minefield. Chrome is relatively well behaved, but as this example demonstrates, it won't let you preload any more that some predefined buffer size. Your example will fall completely apart on other browsers. The worst is Safari on IOS that refuses most kinds of preloading.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to do the same thing. I was preloading 12 audio and 12 image files in preparation for interactive activities based on them.  I was getting the same problem (requests cancelled).

I put together this routine which works for me (Chrome testing done so far).

```
    cacheLessonFiles: function (lessonWords, cacheImg, cacheAudio) {
        var
        fileName = '',
        img = {},
        audio = {},
        wordIDs = Object.keys(lessonWords)
        ;
        wordIDs.forEach(function (wordID) {
            if (cacheImg) {
                fileName = lessonWords[wordID].img || wordID;
                img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    console.log('cache: finished caching ' + this.src);
                };
                img.src = "/img/" + fileName + imageSuffix;
            }
            if (cacheAudio) {
                fileName = lessonWords[wordID].saySpanish || wordID;
                audio = new Audio();
                audio.onloadeddata = function () {
                    console.log('cache: finished caching ' + this.src);
                };
                audioArray.push({a: audio, f:"/audio/" + fileName + audioSuffix});
            }
        });
        setTimeout(loadAudio, AUDIO_LOAD_WAIT);
    },
```

The routine just loads up image files without special handling.  The image files were trickier.  Instead of just setting the source for all of the audio files in the loop, I populated an array with the audio element and associated source file name (.mp3).  I then launched a self-initiating callback in a timeout to process the array, pausing for 200ms between requests.

```
function loadAudio () {
    var
    aud = audioArray.pop()
    ;
    aud.a.src = aud.f;
    if (audioArray.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(loadAudio,  AUDIO_LOAD_WAIT);
    }
}
```

One constant and one variable are within the closure, but outside of the cacheLessonFiles() method.

```
AUDIO_LOAD_WAIT = 200,
audioArray = []
```

I tried wait times less than 200ms, but the cancelled requests started to reappear.

I'd imagine that clients on the end of slower connections (I'm on fiber) would likely get failures again, but this working well enough for my purposes.